# Why eloquent doesn't return error on diffrent primarykey?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I was working on an old database which primarykey is 'Id'. Eloquent set up the primary key to default 'id', so it is little change, but still can be confusing. Of course I didnt notice that, and I wanted to save updated models to database. There was no error, and `$model->save()` return was good but database didn't update. Furthermore I have other functions that get models from  the database, and they work as they should without overriding `$primarykey`.

So here is my question: Why isn't eloquent returning any warnings or errors ? Of course I found in the documentation that I should override `$primarykey` in the model, and then everything worked perfectly.

I was using MySql 10.1.16-MariaDB. 
Here is Laravel controller

```
 public function update(Request $request, Order $order)
     {
        $order->fill($request->get('data'));
        $order->save();
        $order->products;
        return $order;
     }
```

Vue.js function

```
editOrder () {
    this.fullscreenLoading = true
    axios.put('/web/' + this.url + '/' + this.rowId, {'data': this.row})
      .then(({data}) => {
        this.row = data;
        this.fullscreenLoading = false
      });
  },
```

Laravel Model was standard, of course my model is now properly updated, when i got this problem there was no `$primarykey`, I didnt mention `$fillable` and relationship to products but in my project they are defined and working.

```
class Order extends Model
   {
      use LogsActivity;
      protected $table = 'orders';
      protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
      protected $fillable = []
   }
```

Comment: I've answered your question below, but if you need help with some specific query, please show the code.

Comment: If you save without specifying the primary key, then laravel should assume "id" is the primary key. If you don't include an "id" parameter either, then "save" should be creating a brand new row each time you save, and that doesn't return any error because everything worked fine. Isn't that what is happening, one different row each time you save?

Comment: @Amarnasan after save there wasn't brand new row and database dont change at all

Comment: Unless you somehow changed the PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE option, then Laravel would throw an exception if the database returned an error. However, you need to provide more information if you want a more specific answer. For example, show your code, mention which database you're using, show how you determined your statement was run but the database wasn't updated...

Comment: @patricus I edited my question with code that was using to generate this problem

Comment: You're using ajax, so how do you know that laravel didn't throw any errors or warnings? I don't see any error handling code in your javascript. From first glance, Laravel would throw a `MassAssignmentException` error because you're using `fill()`, but your `$fillable` attribute is an empty array.

Comment: @patricus did you saw what I wrote before Model ? I didnt add all `$fillable` becouse of long list, but i have it in my project. When you send ajax, you can see request error on preview/response request in dev tools of your browser.

Comment: What is the result of your ajax call? 2xx or 5xx? What is the content returned from the call? Did you use a sql explorer tool to look in your database to see if the records were actually saved or not? Column names in MariaDB are case-insensitive, so I'm guessing the data saved just fine.

Comment: Result of course was 200, I think this is eloquent problem becouse it doesn't give any error like others said. I think i get my answer. Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't get an error because there was no error.

When you ran `$order->save()`, the query generated would have been something like:

```
update `orders` set `field1` = ?, `fieldN` = ?, `updated_at` = ? where `id` is null
```

This is a perfectly valid SQL statement, and when it runs, it would produce no errors. However, it will also not update any records (unless you do have a record where the `id` is null).

The reason why the update query is using `null` is because your Order model does not have an `id` attribute, it has an `Id` attribute, and PHP array keys are case-sensitive. So, when Laravel attempts to get the value for the `id` attribute, it returns null, and uses that in the query.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the query with `get()`, `create()` or similar method, it will work as before because Eloquent doesn't use PK in this case. But some methods like `find()` will not work for you until you setup `$primaryKey` property in the model.

Comment: thanks for answer, I solve my problems with that, but I want to get knowledge how it works from the bottom of eloquent. I think that elqouent could give warning or error when save is not executed properly. I know that this is described in docs but still could be good to inform.